# JQuery on with multiple events for mutiple elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

No doubt it works but i know it's not a good code.So i want to accomplish

- Make it work using one `on()`

  ```
  <script>
      $(document).on("mouseenter", ".BUTTON_ONE", function() {
          $(this).animate({ 
              \'padding-right\' : 10,
          },30);
      });
      $(document).on("mouseleave", ".BUTTON_ONE", function() {
          $(this).animate({ 
              \'padding-right\' : 4,
          },30);
      });
      $(document).on("mouseenter", ".BUTTON_TWO", function() {
          $(this).animate({ 
              \'padding-left\' : 10,
          },30);
      });
      $(document).on("mouseleave", ".BUTTON_TWO", function() {
          $(this).animate({ 
              \'padding-left\' : 4,
          },30);
      });
      $(document).on("mouseenter", ".BUTTON_THREE", function() {
          $(this).animate({ 
              \'padding-left\' : 10,
          },30);
      });
      $(document).on("mouseleave", ".BUTTON_THREE", function() {
          $(this).animate({ 
              \'padding-left\' : 4,
          },30);
      });
   </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this: :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body)
    .on({
        'mouseenter': function(e) { animate_padding_right(e,10); },
        'mouseleave': function(e) { animate_padding_right(e,4); }
    }, ".BUTTON_ONE")
    .on({
        'mouseenter': function(e) { animate_padding_left(e,10); },
        'mouseleave': function(e) { animate_padding_left(e,4); }
    }, ".BUTTON_TWO,.BUTTON_THREE");
});
function animate_padding_left(e,val) {
    $(e.target).animate({'padding-left':val},30);
}
function animate_padding_right(e,val) {
    $(e.target).animate({'padding-right':val},30);
}
```

Notice that I use `$(document.body)` because it's faster & more effective for this case.

Working fiddle: http://www.codeply.com/go/uUoOo1vlaB

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work , says `missing : after property id` in console

Comment: Ah, sorry for I didn't test my code beforehand >w< I'll check it now

Comment: Wrap `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` with single quotes, so became `'mouseenter'` and `'mouseleave'` :D Hope it work now

Comment: I have corrected my script and it have been tested & run smoothly. :) Hope it helps.